# How to join JSON objects on particular fields using jq?

Tags: json, shell, join, command-line, jq

I have following JSON structure:

```
{
  "Reservations": [
    {
      "Id": "R-1",
      "CustomerId": "1"
    },
    {
      "Id": "R-2",
      "CustomerId": "2"
    }
  ],
  "Customers": [
    {
      "Id": "1",
      "Name": "customer 1"
    },
    {
      "Id": "2",
      "Name": "customer 2"
    },
    {
      "Id": "3",
      "Name": "customer 3"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to join `Reservations` with `Customers` and get something like this:

```
{
  "ReservationId": "R-1",
  "CustomerName": "customer 1"
}
{
  "ReservationId": "R-2",
  "CustomerName": "customer 2"
}
```

I've played with `jq` extensively, tried using multiple filters separated by comma, tried using variables, read the docs, but it seems like doing such a simple tasks is impossible with `jq`. Or, am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution using `INDEX/2`:

```
INDEX(.Customers[]; .Id) as $c
| .Reservations[]
| { ReservationId: .Id,
    CustomerName: $c[.CustomerId].Name }
```

If your jq does not have `INDEX/2` then now would be a good time to upgrade; otherwise, you can copy-and-paste its def from https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/master/src/builtin.jq, or you could use `INDEX/3` as defined below.

### INDEX/3

```
def INDEX(s; k; v):
  reduce s as $x ({}; .[$x|k] = ($x|v));

INDEX(.Customers[]; .Id; .Name) as $c
| .Reservations[]
| { ReservationId: .Id,
    CustomerName: $c[.CustomerId] }
```

Comment: Thanks. Will try.
Any way to do it without SQL-style operators?

Comment: Is INDEX/2 an SQL-style operator?  It just creates a dictionary, which makes everything efficient and straightforward, though not as efficient and straightforward as using INDEX/3 :-)