# Combine files in jq based on similar ID object and reform data

Tags: json, jq

Preface: If the following is not possible with jq, then I completely accept that as an answer and will try to force this with bash.

I have two files that contain some IDs that, with some massaging, should be able to be combined into a single file. I have some content that I'll add to that as well (as seen in output). Essentially "mitre_test" should get compared to "sys_id". When compared, the "mitreid" from in2.json becomes technique_ID in the output (and is generally the unifying field of each output object).

Caveats:

1. There are some junk "desc" values placed in the in1.json that are there to make sure this is as programmatic as possible, and there are actually numerous junk inputs on the true input file I am using.
2. some of the mitre_test values have pairs and are not in a real array. I can split on those and break them out, but find myself losing the other information from in1.json.
3. Notice in the "metadata" for the output that is contains the "number" values from in1.json, and stored in a weird way (but the way that the receiving tool requires).

in1.json

```
[
{
  "test": "Execution",
  "mitreid": "T1204.001",
  "mitre_test": "90b"
},
{
  "test": "Defense Evasion",
  "mitreid": "T1070.001",
  "mitre_test": "afa"
},
{
  "test": "Credential Access",
  "mitreid": "T1556.004",
  "mitre_test": "14b"
},
{
  "test": "Initial Access",
  "mitreid": "T1200",
  "mitre_test": "f22"
},
{
  "test": "Impact",
  "mitreid": "T1489",
  "mitre_test": "fa2"
}
]
```

in2.json

```
[
  {
    "number": "REL0001346",
    "desc": "apple",
    "mitre_test": "afa"
  },
  {
    "number": "REL0001343",
    "desc": "pear",
    "mitre_test": "90b"
  },
  {
    "number": "REL0001366",
    "desc": "orange",
    "mitre_test": "14b,f22"
  },
  {
    "number": "REL0001378",
    "desc": "pineapple",
    "mitre_test": "90b"
  }
]
```

The output:

```
[{
  "techniqueID": "T1070.001",
  "tactic": "defense-evasion",
  "score": 1,
  "color": "",
  "comment": "",
  "enabled": true,
  "metadata": [{
      "name": "DET_ID",
      "value": "REL0001346"
    }],
  "showSubtechniques": true
},
{
  "techniqueID": "T1204.001",
  "tactic": "execution",
  "score": 1,
  "color": "",
  "comment": "",
  "enabled": true,
  "metadata": [{
      "name": "DET_ID",
      "value": "REL0001343"
    },
    {
      "name": "DET_ID",
      "value": "REL0001378"
    }],
  "showSubtechniques": true
},
{
  "techniqueID": "T1556.004",
  "tactic": "credential-access",
  "score": 1,
  "color": "",
  "comment": "",
  "enabled": true,
  "metadata": [{
      "name": "DET_ID",
      "value": "REL0001366"
    }],
  "showSubtechniques": true
},
{
  "techniqueID": "T1200",
  "tactic": "initial-access",
  "score": 1,
  "color": "",
  "comment": "",
  "enabled": true,
  "metadata": [{
      "name": "DET_ID",
      "value": "REL0001366"
    }],
  "showSubtechniques": true
}
]
```

I'm assuming I have some splitting to do on mitre_test with something like `.mitre_test |= split(","))`, and there are some joins I'm assuming, but doing so causes data loss or mixing up of the data. You'll notice the static data in the output exists as well, but is likely easy to place in and as such isn't as much of an issue.

Edit: reduced some of the match IDs so that it is easier to look at while analyzing the in1 and in2 files. Also simplified the two inputs to have a similar structure so that the answer is easier to understand later.

Comment: I'm assuming that I'll need to first baseline the values that are similar by renaming them to something that is the same, then ```jq . in1.json in2.json``` and munge together like items first. I'll continue working on this and hopefully answer my own question, as I'm aware that the question is more indepth than is generally preferred.

Comment: I'm getting closer with the following ```jq . in4.json in3.json | jq '.[] |{number: .number, test: .test, mitreid: .mitreid, mitre_test: .mitre_test}'  | jq -s '. |map(try(.mitre_test |= split(",")) // .)|
.[] | [.number,.test,.mitreid] as $h | .mitre_test[] |$h + [.] | {DET_ID: .[0], tactic: .[1], techniqueID: .[2], mitre_test: .[3]}'```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is probably a much more elegant way to do this, but I ended up manually walking around things and piping to new output.

Explanation:
Read in both files, pull the fields I need.

Break out the mitre_test values that were previously just a comma separated set of values with map and try.

Store the none-changing fields as a variable and then manipulate mitre_test to become an appropriately split array, removing nulls.
Group by mitre_test values, since they are the common thing that the output is based on.

Cleanup more nulls.

Sort output to look like I want it.

```
jq . in1.json in2.json | \
jq '.[] |{number: .number, test: .test, mitreid: .mitreid, mitre_test: .mitre_test}'  |\
jq -s '[. |map(try(.mitre_test |= split(",")) // .)|\
.[] | [.number,.test,.mitreid] as $h | .mitre_test[] |$h + [.] | \
{DET_ID: .[0], tactic: .[1], techniqueID: .[2], mitre_test: .[3]}] |\
del(.[][] | nulls)' |jq '[group_by(.mitre_test)[]|{mitre_test: .[0].mitre_test, techniqueID: [.[].techniqueID],tactic: [.[].tactic], DET_ID: [.[].DET_ID]}]|\
del(.[].techniqueID[] | nulls) | del(.[].tactic[] | nulls) | del(.[].DET_ID[] | nulls)' | \
jq '.[]| [{techniqueID: .techniqueID[0],tactic: .tactic[0], metadata: [{name: "DET_ID",value: .DET_ID[]}]}] | .[] | \
select((.metadata|length)>0)'
```

It was a long line, so I split it among some of the basic ideas.

Answer (score 0):

The requirements are somewhat opaque but it's fairly clear that if the task can be done by computer, it can be done using jq.

From the description, it would appear that one of the unusual aspects of the problem is that the "dictionary" defined by in1.json must be derived by splitting the key names that are CSV (comma-separated values).  Here therefore is a jq def that will do that:

```
# Input: a JSON dictionary for which some keys are CSV,
# Output: a JSON dictionary with the CSV keys split on the commas
def refine:
  . as $in
  | reduce keys_unsorted[] as $k ({};
    if ($k|index(","))
    then ($k/",") as $keys
    | . + ($keys | map( {(.): $in[$k]}) | add)
    else .[$k] = $in[$k]
    end );
```

You can see how this works by running:

```
INDEX($mitre.records[]; .mitre_test) | refine
```

using an invocation of jq such as:

```
jq --argfile mitre in1.json -f program.jq in2.json
```

For the joining part of the problem, there are many relevant Q&As on SO, e.g.

[How to join JSON objects on particular fields using jq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54506913/how-to-join-json-objects-on-particular-fields-using-jq)